# Errors on MvxBind and MvxItemTemplate with a custom control that inherits from MvxListView

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I get bind error during the loading of the view, the App keeps running but no visuals in the ListView.

I get the following error on the MvxBind:  (and something same on MvxItemTemplate)

> MvxBind:   9.11 Problem seen during binding execution for binding
>   ItemsSource for IsolationCertificate.IsolationPoints - problem
>   TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.

This happens on a custom control where I manualy want to add a HeaderView and control it later on. Therefore I needed the following construction;

```
    public class MvxPaddedListView : MvxListView
{

    public View Padder;

    public MvxPaddedListView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) 
        : base(context, attrs, null)
    {
        SetFlexibleHeader(context);

        var itemTemplateId = MvxAttributeHelpers.ReadListItemTemplateId(context, attrs);
        Adapter = new MvxAdapter(context) { ItemTemplateId = itemTemplateId };
    }

    protected MvxPaddedListView(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {

    }

    private void SetFlexibleHeader(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            Padder = new View(context);
            AddHeaderView(Padder);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }

}
```

Is there a common reason Why the MvxBind and MvxItemTemplate won't work anymore when inheriting from MvxListView?

Edit: its maybe good to point out I use a NULL in the MvxListView constructor to prevent early adapter creation

Comment: @stuart  any clue why bindings wint worm anymore with my MvxListView implementation? (when changing the control back to the original MvxListView all works perfectly)

Comment: @cheesebaron maybe you have some cheese for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a working solution on: http://blog.masterdevs.com/headers-and-footers-on-an-mvxlistview/

MVVMCross was discussing a simular issue on:
https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/602